# Display loading gif while page is loading

Tags: jquery, ajax, tabs, loading

I have a tabbed menu.

```
<ul>
    <a href="views/wrap1.php"><li class="wrap1"> Home &nbsp&nbsp </li></a>&nbsp
    <a href="views/wrap2.php"><li class="wrap2"> Packages</li></a>&nbsp
    <a href="views/wrap3.php"><li class="wrap3"> Clients &nbsp </li></a>&nbsp
    <a href="views/wrap4.php"><li class="wrap4"> Creations</li></a>&nbsp
    <a href="views/wrap5.php"><li class="wrap5"> Reach Us &nbsp </li></a>&nbsp
</ul>
```

And using Jquery.load() i load five pages wrap1.php , wrap2.php , wrap3.php , wrap4.php , wrap5.php
into a common div **container**

The Jquery code i am using is

```
$('.wrap1').css({'border':'2px solid black'}) ;
     $('#tabs li').click(function(){


     $('#container').load('views/'+$(this).attr("class")+'.php', function(){

     $('#container').fadeIn('slow') ;
        });
        return false;
    });
```

**Everything is working fine** but i want to display a loading gif when the page loads up and hide that gif when the page has loaded. I read many questions here and tried each and everything but nothing worked for me. Also do tell me that where should i put a script so that it may work

Comment: What exactly have you tried? I find it hard to believe nothing worked, as doing this is extremely simple. Also, all scripts should go in `<head>`

Comment: @colleen. I tried many methods to put a loader but none seemed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go through jQuery for this. jQuery provides you lots of animation event or functions.

Click here [jQuery Image Loader](http://mycodeprograms.blogspot.com/2012/10/how-to-add-loader-while-page-load.html) for see some nice example that you can use in your code.